# python regex help: match all text between '"icon":"' AND '.png",'

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to erase all results of this pattern in a string.

```
,"icon":"Art\/2DArt\/SkillIcons\/passives\/evadepercentage.png"
,"icon":"Art\/2DArt\/SkillIcons\/passives\/evadepercentage.png"
,"icon":"Art\/2DArt\/SkillIcons\/passives\/evade.png"  
,"icon":" [[ anything could be here ]] .png"

txt = re.sub('"icon":"(.*).png",','',txt)
```

### My attempt:

```
import re

txt = '{21435,"icon":"Art\/2DArt\/SkillIcons\/passives\/newevadepercentage.png",false,true,"Leather and Steel",false,[],["24% increased Evasion Rating and Armour"],439,2,10,0,0,0,[]},{50054,"icon":"Art\/2DArt\/SkillIcons\/passives\/shieldblock.png",false,false,"Shield Block",false,[],["2% additional Shield Block Chance"],440,1,4,0,0,0,[24083]},{44207,"icon":"Art\/2DArt\/SkillIcons\/passives\/barricade.png",false,true,"Shield Mastery",false,[],["4% additional Shield Block Chance","20% increased Defences from equipped Shield"],440,1,0,0,0,0,[59281]},{59281,"icon":"Art\/2DArt\/SkillIcons\/passives\/shieldblock.png",false,false,"Shield Block",false,[],["2% additional Shield Block Chance"],440,1,2,0,0,0,[50054]}'

txt = re.sub('"icon":"(.*).png",','',txt)

print txt
```

### Output:

```
{21435,false,false,"Shield Block",false,[],["2% additional Shield Block Chance"],440,1,2,0,0,0,[50054]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about :-

```
txt = re.sub('"icon":"(.*?).png",','',txt)
```

To do a non greedy match.

**Tested :-**

```
    C:\>python st.py
{21435,false,true,"Leather and Steel",false,[],["24% increased Evasion Rating and Armour"],439,2,10,0,0,0,[]},
{50054,false,false,"Shield Block",false,[],["2% additional Shield Block Chance"],440,1,4,0,0,0,[24083]},
{44207,false,true,"Shield Mastery",false,[],["4% additional Shield Block Chance","20% increased Defences from equipped Shield"],440,1,0,0,0,0,[59281]},
{59281,false,false,"Shield Block",false,[],["2% additional Shield Block Chance"],440,1,2,0,0,0,[50054]}
```